# Android OkHttp addPathSegment replaces slashes

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 2.4.0.

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("www.something.com")
            .addPathSegment("/api/v1/doc")
            .build();
```

The expected url is: https://www.something.com/api/v1/doc

What I get is: https://www.something.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fdoc

The "/" in the pathSegment are replaced with "%2F". Why does this occur and how can it be avoided since i get an invalid Url exception because apache does not allow "%2F" in a url.

Comment: name of the method is `pathSegments` or `pathSegment` ? also i'm pretty sure that result is `https://www.something.com/%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fdoc` not `https://www.something.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fdoc`

Comment: See @PAD's comment below. The issue here I believe is `addPathSegment` is being used instead of `addPathSegments` and the URL path segment(s) are starting with a `\` or `/` which is hinted at in [their documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/-builder/add-path-segments/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
        .scheme("https")
        .host("www.something.com")
        .addPathSegment("api")
        .addPathSegment("v1")
        .addPathSegment("doc")
        .build();
```

Comment: You can also do a `.addPathSegments("api/v1/doc");` (note the S)

Comment: It causes `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException baseUrl must end in /`, so only `addPathSegments` works

Answer (score 20):

This solution is a little bit more elegant, and OkHttp doesn't replace slashes in this case :)

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host("www.something.com")
    .addPathSegments("api/v1/doc")
    .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the slashes and concatenate the segments like this:

```
HttpUrl url=new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host("www.something.com")
    .addPathSegment("api")
    .addPathSegment("v1")
    .addPathSegment("doc")
    .build();
```